# Getting Failed to construct kafka producer when running the app in azure kubernates

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, confluent-platform

I have a Springboot application which sends a message to a Topic (Lenses Kafka)
The application is running fine when i run in my local environment but when i deploy my app in aks spoke 2 cluster it is giving me failed to construct kafka producer .

I have compared the producer config values from log and able to see just a difference between ssl protocol

```
    acks = 1
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [*************.azure.glb.confluent.cloud:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = producer-1
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
    enable.idempotence = false
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.auto.downgrade.txn.commit = true
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 2147483647
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = [hidden]
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = PLAIN
    security.protocol = SASL_SSL
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    <b>ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]</b>
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    <b>ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2<b>
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
```

the above highlighted ones are the only difference when I run spring boot app locally inside my eclipse

```
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
```

Not sure whether the above change causing the issue as I can see TLSv1.2 is the one getting printed in azure aks spoke cluster pod logs.

I dont think there is an issue with code as it works perfectly inside my eclipse

```
Mon Nov 1 04:03:42.573 | |  |  |  | INFO  | [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] | org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.close | [Producer clientId=producer-56] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 0 ms.
Mon Nov 1 04:03:42.574 | |  |  |  | ERROR | [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] | com.KafkaProducerServiceImpl.publish| exception in Publish to kafkaFailed to construct kafka producer
```

Can some one help ?

```
package com.service.implementation;

import static com.constants.Constants.PUBLISH_FAILURE;
import static com.constants.Constants.PUBLISH_SUCCESS;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.ModelDTO;
import com.KafkaProducerService;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Service
@Slf4j
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaProducerServiceImpl implements KafkaProducerService {

    @Value("${sniT.kafka.producer.topic}")
    private String topic;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, ModelDTO> KafkaTemplate;

    /**
     * publishes messages to confluent Kafka
     * 
     * @param request
     */
    @Override
    public String publish(ModelDTO request) {
        log.trace("Entering publish");

        String response = PUBLISH_SUCCESS;
        String Id = null;
        try {
            Id = request.DTO().getId();
            final ProducerRecord<String, ModelDTO> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<String, ModelDTO>(
                    topic, Id, request);
            KafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("exception in Publish to kafka" + e.getMessage());
            response = PUBLISH_FAILURE;
        }
        log.trace("Exiting publish");
        return response;
    }
}
```

ProducerConfig

```
package com.config;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.CommonClientConfigs;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner;
import org.apache.kafka.common.config.SaslConfigs;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer;

import com.dto.ModelDTO;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Value("${kafka.producer.properties.security.protocol}")
    private String securityProtocol;

    @Value("${kafka.producer.properties.sasl.mechanism}")
    private String saslMechanism;

    @Value("${kafka.producer.properties.sasl.jaas.config}")
    private String jaasConfig;

    public ProducerConfig() {
        log.trace("---producerConfig---");
    }

    /**
     * @return producerFactory Configuration Properties
     */
    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, ModelDTO> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, DefaultPartitioner.class);
        configProperties.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, securityProtocol);
        configProperties.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM, saslMechanism);
        // session time out property for producer config
        configProperties.put(SaslConfigs.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG, jaasConfig);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, ModelDTO>(configProperties);
    }

    /**
     * @return KafkaTemplate Definition
     */
    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, ModelDTO> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<String, ModelDTO>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your code that prints `exception in Publish shipment to kafka`

Comment: added in the question

Comment: And the `KafkaTemplate` bean / config?

Comment: added the config. Again The code works well inside eclipse but when i run in aks it is giving me the error.

Comment: Well, maybe your local JVM has the correct keystore/truststore and the container JVM does not. I suggest you actually run the docker container that it built rather than just running from the IDE

Comment: ok keystore/trustore something needs to be setup in aks ?

Comment: i am reading from apache kafka which works well and publishing it to lenses kafka which has issue

Comment: I understood that. AKS (Kubernetes) runs Docker containers. The container has a JVM. But that JVM is not the same as your IDE JVM. If you are using TLS settings, then you need JKS keys and TLS certs added to the keystore... If you are consuming from Confluent Cloud, you will need certificates, and you cannot use the same client configs to produce to a different cluster

Comment: Also, I don't know what "Lenses Kafka" means. I am only familar with their locally running "Lenses Box" docker image, but your bootstrap servers clearly indicate you're using Confluent Cloud, and not that